# Localhost Error connection refused " Ionic serve "

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Image "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqT24.png"

I am try to lunch the app Ionic in the web browser with " Ionic serve " but the browser don't open automaticaly and when I enter the adress localhost:8100 I get the error "Error connection refused" So I need your help to solve this problem ; Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: the image that you added did not correlate with the question.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the port 8100 is already in use.